# Ngrx Store.select returns List of Map objects instead of js object

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to get a slice of state, which contains an array of IPlace objects:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select('places').subscribe(res => console.log('res', res));
}
```

IPlace interface:

```
export interface IPlace {
    name: string;
    id: number; 
    coords: ICoords;
}
```

So I expect to receive in my console something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlsjy.png): plain JavaScript object

Instead Store returns a [list of Maps objects:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGjJZ.png)

I couldn't find any solution about this. I can't get what I'm missing. (is it an issue of ngrx or rxjs?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please create a minimal working example that will demonstrate your problem

Comment: It appears that [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) - or something very similar - is being used. That's not down to ngrx. It would have been a choice made, by whoever authored the code, when the reducers were composed.

Comment: @cartant, you are absolutely right. Thanks for hint! I was playing with [MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal starter](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal). And they were using Immutable.js